# How to get the selected rows from all pages in the data tables using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a data table which contains the list of data and I want the selected rows to be displayed in popup with another datatable in which the selected rows should be displayed.

the following is the picture of my datatable
[image]

After Selecting two rows from the datatable ,I want to show them in separate popup when user clicks a button

And I want the popup like this

[image]

in the popup I want to display the selected rows should be displayed in it.

I am trying these code but it's not working fine for me

```
  $("#table-sparkline").dataTable().fnDestroy();    
        var oTable2 = $('#table-sparkline').dataTable({
                    "aaSorting": []
        });//popup datatable

//maintable
    $("#example1 tr.selected>td").each(function() {
               //alert("in nth child");
               var values = $(this).html(); 
for(var j=i;j<values.length;j++){
       oTable2.fnAddData([
                values [i]
                ]);

 }
       });
```

popup html code:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Tests' performance</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="result"></div>
                <table id="table-sparkline" class="display table table-bordered num-right-alignct">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>TestName</th>
            <th>Oct-2014</th>
             <th>Nov-2014</th>
              <th>Dec-2014</th>
               <th>Jan-2014</th>
                <th>Feb-2014</th>
                 <th>Mar-2014</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody-sparkline">

</tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok,I will update you

Answer (score 0):

```
var tablevalues =[];

    $("#table-sparkline").dataTable().fnDestroy();  
    var oTable2 = $('#table-sparkline').dataTable({
                "aaSorting": []
    });
    oTable2.fnClearTable();

               //alert("in nth child");
               //var values = $(this).html();        
               //alert(values);
        var table = $('#example1').DataTable(); 
        tablevalues.length=0;
        tablevalues=(table.rows('.selected').data());
        for(var i=0;i<tablevalues.length;i++){

        oTable2.fnAddData([
                tablevalues[i]
                ]);


        }
```

Comment: It is only giving the current page selected rows ,how can we get all the selected rows across the pages ?

Comment: Any answer here?

Answer (score -1):

Using some of your code I was able to pull the data from one row. Examining it should help you on your quest ;)

```js
$("#table-sparkline").find("td").click(function () {
        var message = "";
        var data = $($(this).parent().children()).map(function () {
            message += $(this).text() + ', ';
        });
        alert(message.substring(0,message.length-2));
    });
```

```css
tr:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Tests' performance</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="result"></div>
                <table id="table-sparkline" class="display table table-bordered num-right-alignct">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>TestName</th>
                            <th>Oct-2014</th>
                            <th>Nov-2014</th>
                            <th>Dec-2014</th>
                            <th>Jan-2014</th>
                            <th>Feb-2014</th>
                            <th>Mar-2014</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tbody-sparkline"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: click on a row to activate